# Toggling visibility of a div but adding JavaScript styling messes it up

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a div that is set to display:none when the page first loads.  I then added a js file to set it to become visible when a button is pressed.

So I got the toggling of the visibility to work when the button is pressed but now when I'm adding a js function to make it slide down into the page (instead of just making it appear and disappear) it makes the div show on page load and sets the visibility of the div to not hidden?

If anyone has any idea why this is happening or a way to fix it that would help a lot!  Thanks!

js file

```
var settingVisibility = false;

function showSettings() {
    if (settingVisibility) {
        document.getElementById("pan").style.display = "none";
    settingVisibility = false;
} else {
    document.getElementById("pan").style.display = "block";
    settingVisibility = true;
}
}
```

html file

```
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#pan").slideDown(450);});

    </script>


    <div id = "pan">
        <ul>
            <li>List 1</li>
            <li><input type = "checkbox">Item 1</li>
            <li><input type = "checkbox">Item 2</li>
            <li>List 2</li>
            <li><input type = "checkbox">Item 1</li>
            <li><input type = "checkbox">Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

css file

```
#pan {

position:fixed;
right:0;
display:none;

}
```

Comment: could you share some code?

Comment: yea i'll edit the post

Comment: when is `showSettings()`  is being called?? Also `slideDown` is placed above the HTML so it will execute on page load & display the div#pan on page load only.

Comment: <button class = "settings button" onclick="showSettings()">Settings</button>                my bad forgot to add that too

Comment: `$("#pan").slideDown(450);` Use this code inside the `showSettings()` ...pls edit your code to gve more clearity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/quficuvowi/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)**

`slideDown` is triggered once the page is loaded and it overrides the `display:none` property of the element mentioned in css.

It should be actually inside the `showSettings()` function.

One more suggestion, the showSettings() function can be like this:

```
function showSettings() {
   if(document.getElementById("pan").style.display==="block") {
      document.getElementById("pan").style.display = "none";
   } else {
      $("#pan").slideDown(450);;
   } 
}
```

Comment: just a little followup.. do you know how I would make it slide back up?

Comment: Try this : function showSettings() {
   if(document.getElementById("pan").style.display==="block") {
      $("#pan").slideUp(450);
   } else {
      $("#pan").slideDown(450);
   } 
}

Answer (score 0):

`slideDown` function animates the element and makes it visible.
If you want the element to hide on page load, remove the `$("#pan").slideDown(450);` line from the docuemnt ready part, and add when you want to show the element (as in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UGUKeSB2gAFh9INmAQ19?p=preview)):

```
var settingVisibility = false;

function showSettings() {
    if (settingVisibility) {
        document.getElementById("pan").style.display = "none";
    settingVisibility = false;
} else {
    $("#pan").slideDown(450);
    settingVisibility = true;
}
}
```